# Java - Same method from parent but using individual attributes of each child

Tags: java, generics, methods, parameters, attributes

I have a doubt in my code :

```
public abstract class Jogador {

    String nome;
    int    pontos;
    Jogador (String n) {
        nome = n;
    }
    void aumentaPontos () {
        pontos++;
    }
    abstract <U extends Jogador> boolean melhor (U outro);
}  


class JogadorAdivinha extends Jogador {

    JogadorAdivinha (String n) {
        super(n);
    }

    boolean melhor (JogadorAdivinha outro) {
        if (this.pontos > outro.pontos)
            return true;
        return false;
    }
}  


class JogadorMemoria extends Jogador {
    int rodadasGanhas;

    JogadorMemoria(String n) {
        super(n);
    }

    boolean melhor(JogadorMemoria outro) {
        if (this.rodadasGanhas > outro.rodadasGanhas)
            return true;
        return false;
    }

    void aumentaRodadasGanhas() {
        rodadasGanhas++;
    }

}
```

I'll have compilation problem at both the child classes of Jogador.
But as you can see, only JogadorMemoria has rodadasGanhas.
So, I want to know a way to handle this situation .... if I put as parameter the class Jogador for the method melhor() , I won't be able to receive the children ...
What can I do about it to override the abstract method and to not create a bad smell ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to implement a method like this in subclasses:

```
abstract <U extends Jogador> boolean melhor (U outro);
```

You have to provide [override-equivalent](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.4.2) implementations, like:

```
<U extends Jogador> boolean melhor (U outro) { return true; }
```

You can't drop type variables in subclasses, as the abstract method's declaration says that it has to be able to accept *any* instance of `Jogador` as a parameter to the `melhor` method.

---

If you want to have specific parameter types on those methods, you define the type variable at class-level:

```
public abstract class Jogador<U extends Jodador<U>> {
  abstract boolean melhor (U outro);
}
```

and then you can implement this in the subclasses:

```
class JogadorAdivinha extends Jogador<JogadorAdivinha> {
  boolean melhor (JogadorAdivinha outro) { return true; }
}
```

Comment: That's exactly what I was looking for ! I'm still at noob level in Java ... I've never read about generics (Ive put it in my code, but I didnt understand of of its functionality .. and I still don't hahahaha).